# How can I solve race condition for Golang WAF service?

Tags: go, race-condition

Firstly, sorry all for bad English.

I try to develop a WAF(Web Application Firewall) service in Golang. Everything is in the `map[string]*Struct{}` in memory. When request has come, I set request header's host to map in handler function.

`host,err := GetHost(r.Host)`

```
func GetHost(host string) (*Host,error){
    split, _, err := net.SplitHostPort(host)
    if err == nil {
        host = split
    }
    if data, val := hosts[host]; val { 
        return data, nil
    }
    return nil,errors.New("host not found!)
}
//hosts is a map for all host, key is host and value is host struct.
```

The problem is, map is messing when service has got a lot of request. For example;
host is `example.com` but `hosts["example.com"]` gives an another value which is irrelevant.

```
type Server struct {
    mu   sync.RWMutex
    Host *models.Host
}
```

```
func (c *Server) handler(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    var err error
    c.Host, err = GetHost(r.Host)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadGateway)
        w.Write([]byte(r.Host + " not found!!"))
        return
    }
    //it's going on..Edited part
```

So, I try to use `mutex` and `wg` for solving this problem but it didn't work. Open for any suggestion.

Comment: Can you share an example of how did you try to use mutex?

Comment: "it didn't work" What exactly happened? More detail is needed. One issue I perceive is that your _critical section_ (the code between the acquisition and release of the lock) does too much; it shouldn't do any I/O. Your mutex, as used, is likely to be the source of much contention in your server.

Comment: @jub0bs For example, the request comes for "example.com", I need to find hosts["example.com"]. it has to be `hosts["example.com"] = { domain: "example.com", status: "404", ...}` but when a lot of requests come, I've got `hosts["example.com"] = { domain: "foo.com", status: "200", ...}`

Comment: @Drizzt Where, in the code of your handler, do you access your map?

Comment: @jub0bs yeah, I can.

Comment: In `c.Host, err = GetHost(r.Host)` what is `c`? Where do you put data in map?

Comment: So far It's also not clear what you trying to achieve. Looks like you are using some global map but you want it to be request-local. If so, consider to use `request.Context()` or just pass around all the values as function arguments

Comment: @MaximKosov I've updated the question. c is a struct and handler is a method function so I can access to the map. I'll try `request.Context()`.

Comment: @Drizzt What "didn't work" still isn't clear. Did using a mutex not resolve the race condition? Or did it make your server unresponsive? Also, could you share the implementation of your `GetHost` function?

Comment: ```split, _, err := net.SplitHostPort(host)
if err == nil {
    host = split
}
if data, val := hosts[host]; val { 
    return data, nil
}
return nil,errors.New("host not found!)``` this part from `GetHost()`

Comment: @Drizzt And where is `hosts` declared? At the package level?

Comment: @jub0bs yes, it is global variable

Comment: @Drizzt We're getting somewhere, but please explain "it didn't work".

Comment: @jub0bs at first, everything was normal cause my service get minimal requests, but my service started to get a lot of requests, the structor showed up race condition problem. "It didn't work" is nothing changes for me. The `GetHost` function returns wrong struct.

Comment: @jub0bs `var (
 hosts map[string]*Host
)` is the `hosts` map

Comment: I started writing an answer but I noticed something weird in your code. Why does your handler update the `Host` field of your `Server` struct, exactly? What's the point?

Comment: yeah, handler function is method function, I use it for another function in same package. So I need to update the `Host` field for every request.(Notice that, requests could come to another hosts for everytime).

Comment: In case you haven't found it yet, look for the Go race detector. Very handy. I believe it is the `-race` flag when building.

Comment: @Drizzt Any feedback on my answer? Does it help?

Comment: @jubs0bs I'm so sorry for late answer. Thank you so much for helping. Mostly, it does but now the service comes to a deadlock which I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @jub0bs Oh, it was my fault. Deadlock becomes another package so your answer is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in thinking that you need to serialise access to a shared state from a HTTP handler (because the server handles each HTTP request in a dedicated goroutine). Otherwise, your program would indeed suffer from a synchronization bug that would likely manifest itself as a data race during execution, as you seem to have experienced; the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector) provided with the Go toolchain would likely have picked up on it.

Arguably, the simplest way to serialize access to that shared state is to use some mutex. However, you need to be careful. Your deferred call to `mutex.Unlock` is problematic, for at least one, possibly two reasons:

1. In general, you should endeavour to keep the *critical section* (the part of your code that surrounded by a call to `Lock` and `Unlock`) as "small" and "cheap" as possible. In short, the critical section should only do in-memory treatments, not I/O stuff. Here, the lock needs to be held during the entire treatment of each request, which is likely to cause a great deal of contention for your server.
2. Although you omitted the end of the code in your handler, I'm guessing (?) that you also acquire the lock later in order to update the map (if the current request's host hasn't been encountered before). But, because none of the mutex types exported by package `sync` are re-entrant, you're likely to get a deadlock: due to the call to `Unlock` being deferred, the mutex will only get released when your handler terminates.

One solution consists in eschewing `defer` and restricting the critical section to the call to your `GetHost` function.

Another improvement would be to [eliminate global state](https://twitter.com/peterbourgon/status/1133492111012184064), for better testability, etc. You could make your `hosts` map non-global by simply smuggling storing it in a field of your `Server` struct and declaring `GetHost` as a method on `*Server`.

```
type Server struct {
    mu   sync.RWMutex
    Host *models.Host
    hosts map[string]*Host
}

func (srv *Server) GetHost(host string) (*Host, error){
    split, _, err := net.SplitHostPort(host)
    if err == nil {
        host = split
    }
    if data, exists := srv.hosts[host]; exists { 
        return data, nil
    }
    return nil, errors.New("host not found!")
}

func (srv *Server) handler(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        mutex.Lock()
        srv.Host, err := srv.GetHost(r.Host)
        mutex.Unlock()
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadGateway)
            w.Write([]byte(r.Host + " not found!!"))
            return
        }
        // possibly acquire and release the lock again
        // for further treatment of the hosts map
    })
}
```

I may be missing something, but must admit I don't see the point in updating the `Host` field of your `Server` struct for each request...

Comment: In addition, rather than potentially creating a new error value during calls to `GetHost`, you may want to define a package-level, unexported error variable: `var errNoSuchHost = errors.New("host not found!")`.